# MySQL: OPTIMIZE TABLE vs. myisamchk

Tags: mysql, myisam, mysql-5.1

I have a very large table (~50GB) and periodically rows are purged
from it and I want to run `OPTIMIZE TABLE` to recover the space. But I
do not have enough space to run it. If I do run it the server hangs
and must be killed and restarted and the table is damaged and must be
repaired. I do this with myisamchk.

At [the MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/myisam-optimization.html) I read this:

> To coalesce fragmented rows and eliminate wasted space that results
>   from deleting or updating rows, run myisamchk in recovery mode:
>
> ```
> shell> myisamchk -r tbl_name
> ```
>
> You can optimize a table in the same way by using the `OPTIMIZE TABLE`
>   SQL statement. `OPTIMIZE TABLE` does a table repair and a key
>   analysis, and also sorts the index tree so that key lookups are
>   faster. There is also no possibility of unwanted interaction between a
>   utility and the server, because the server does all the work when you
>   use `OPTIMIZE TABLE`.

Does this mean that `myisamchk -r -a -S` does the same thing as `OPTIMIZE TABLE`?

If they do do the same thing, why does myisamchk work but `OPTIMIZE
TABLE` run out of space?

Comment: This is 2015, please use innodb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They do the same thing, but there is a difference and a grave danger.

Here is the difference:

- `OPTIMIZE TABLE` is done in the mysql client or in a mysql session.
- `myisamchk` is a utility, not a client. Thus, there are no table locking safeguards. Therefore, you should never run `myisamchk -r -a -S` in a live system. Otherwise, you can quickly (in fact, instantaneously) corrupt a MyISAM table.

You could move the MyISAM table to another folder and run `myisamchk` against the table files without interference from mysqld or any client connections thereof.

Other difference

- mysqld will create temp tables
- myisamchk can figure out if it needs to make a temp table or do things in place.

More info

Doing `OPTIMIZE TABLE` will does a complete copy of the table. It does this under the hood

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ENGINE=MyISAM;
ANALYZE TABLE mytable;
```

Doing `OPTIMIZE TABLE` could make the temp table in `/tmp` and not in place like `myisamchk`

Please remember that [tmpdir](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_tmpdir) is mapped somewhere. That's where space may give out.

Comment: Yes, I know - I am running myisamchk when the server is down.

Comment: But why does OPTIMIZE TABLE use up all the disk space whereas myisamchk does not do that?

Comment: Look at my `Other difference`

Comment: Because it's not locking the table? Is that what consumes the space?

Comment: `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'tbl_name';` -- Let's see how much "Data_free" there is.

Comment: Are you purging "old" rows?  If so, I can suggest a way using PARTITION to avoid your problem.

Comment: The machine I was working on has crashed, so I can't get the table status until it comes back up. But this is something that we will be doing on every client site, so the data_free will most likely be different on each site. 

Yes, these are 'old' rows. We have not been purging old data. Some of our clients have 4, 5, 6 or more years of data. We will be purging data older than 3 years. I look forward to hearing your method of using PARTITION. Thanks!